# Sharing modules b/w host and remote via Module Federation for npm scoped packages

Tags: webpack, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I'm trying to share a component library via module federation and npm b/w host and remote.

1. Host consumes the component library via federation
2. Remote consumes the component library via npm

Both consume the same version of component library.

**The problem is:** They don't share a single copy of the component library instead app1 *(host)* and app2 *(remote)* downloads their own components. Basically making two request for a single version of components.

So, I tried replicating the same with the [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) library. Now the host and the remote consumed only a single copy of it.

Feels like the culprit is @scoped/packages. NPM based scoped packages.

Also the component library has two configs for npm and federated app.

How do we share and use a single copy of a npm package for host and remote via federation and npm respectively.

For reference:

app1 federation config

```
{
    remotes: {
       app2: 'app2@http://localhost:3002/remoteEntry.app3.js',
       'classnames-library': "", // CDN URL
       '@scoped/components': `scopedComponents@URL`, // CDN Url
    },
    shared: {},
}
```

app2 federation config

```
shared: 
{
   classnames: {
     singleton: true,
     strictVersion: false,
   },
   '@scoped/components': {
     shareKey: 'scopedComponents', // Tried using this
     singleton: true,
     strictVersion: true,
   },
},
```